# Page refresh binds backbone events twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have created an extensive app using Backbone. So far, everything works very well. However, when I refresh/reload a page on a given hash (e.g. myapp/#dashboard), the view is rendered twice and all events are bound twice. If I go to another section and come back. everything is working normally.

I use a subrouter that looks like this:

```
var DashboardRouter = Backbone.SubRoute.extend({
    routes : {
        /* matches http://yourserver.org/books */
        "" : "show",
    },

    authorized : function() {
        // CODE TO RETRIEVE CURRENT USER ID ...
        return (lg);
    },

    show : function() {
        var usr = this.authorized();
        if (this.dashboardView) {
            this.dashboardView.undelegateEvents();
        }
        switch(usr) {
            case 2:
                this.dashboardView = new StudentDashboard();
                break;
            case 3:
                this.dashboardView = new CounsellorDashboard();
                break;
            case 4:
                this.dashboardView = new AdminDashboard();
                break;
            default:
                location.replace('#signout');
        }
    },
});
```

I have checked within the console, and the events here are called only once. The student dashboard looks like this (extract)

```
DashboardView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el : "#maincontent",
    template : tpl,
    model : new Student(),
    events : {
        "click #edit-dashboard" : "editDashboard",
        "click #add-grade" : "addGrade",
        "click #add-test" : "addTest",
        "click #add-eca" : "addECA"
    },
    initialize : function() {
        // BIND EVENTS
        _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'editDashboard', 'renderGrades', 'renderTests', 'renderECAs', 'renderPreferences');
        this.model.on("change", this.render);
        this.model.id = null;
        this.model.fetch({
            success : this.render
        });
    },

    render : function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        // set location variables after main template is loaded on DOM
        ...
        if (!this.gradeList) { this.renderGrades(); };
        if (!this.testList) { this.renderTests(); };
        if (!this.ecaList) { this.renderECAs(); };
        if (!this.preferencesView) { this.renderPreferences(); };
        this.delegateEvents();
        return this;
    },
```

From the console logs I know that all the subviews are rendered normally only once, but twice when I refresh the page, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Not sure if this is a problem but `model : new Student()` is an odd thing to do, that puts a single `new Student` in the `DashboardView` prototype so the same model instance will be shared by all your view instances. You probably want `this.model = new Student` in your view's `initialize` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure all events on your view are undeligated before re-rendering it.

Add following function inside your views.

```
cleanup: function() {
    this.undelegateEvents();
    $(this.el).empty();
}
```

Now, in your router before rendering the view, do the cleanup if the view already exists.

```
if (this.myView) { this.myView.cleanup() };
this.myView = new views.myView();
```